# Find shortest path using A Star with difficult restriction

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I need to solve the following problem:
I have a grid in which you can move in 8 directions, N,S,E,W,NE,NW,SE,SW.

Moving orthogonally costs always 1. Moving diagonally costs 1 if the previous move was orthogonal or if the previous move was diagonal and cost 2, else it costs 2.

So a few examples to explain better:

1. moving NE,NE will cost 1+2 = 3
2. moving NE,E,NE will cost 1+1+1 = 3
3. moving NE,NE,NE will cost 1+2+1 = 4

I think that's enough to get the gist of it.

I don't know how to implement an A* algorithm that would achieve this. My heurestic function:

```
private double heuresticDistance(Node p1, Node p2){
        double dx = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
        double dy = Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y);
        // D = 1d, D2 = 1.5d;
        return D * (dx + dy) + (D2 - 2 * D) * Math.min(dx, dy);
    }
```

Obviously it's not good in this case and there are some cases where it will not go the shortest path(cost-wise), meaning that it could have gone a different way that would result in a lower cost.

It is really important that it will always find the cheapest or one of the cheapest if there are more than one.

Could you give me some hints? My A* implementation is pretty straightforward I guess I wrote it according to the wikipedia pseudocode.

EDIT:

```
public class Node{
    public int x,y;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `Node`?

Comment: It's not a homework assignment. I am writing a game and this is something that I need to implement so that it works correctly. 
@David Node contains just x and y coordinates.

Comment: does the grid have obstacles?

Comment: It does. But the path I want to find will always exist because it is previously checked(Using a recursive function that knows the remaining move points to spend and whether it came from diagonal move and how much did the previous move cost). Each Node has 8 neighbours unless there are obstacles. I have information about which grid cell is taken and a function that generates nodes neighbours using that information(it creates 8 neighbours and removes the ones that are blocked)

Answer (score 2):

Your heuristic function is not [admissible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic).

Look at the path from `(0, 0)` to `(1, 1)`. Your heuristics tells you that it is equal to `1 * (1 + 1) + (1.5 - 2) * 1 = 1.5`. But the path is `1`. So you overestimate your goal, thus make your heuristic in-admissible and this cause A* to find the wrong path.

Take a closer look at A* and you will see that it requires admissibility (also I do not remember whether the consistency is important for your case).

Comment: Is it enough that I write a function that always finds the lowest cost between two nodes in a grid without obstacles in order for it to find the shortest path? Or does it have to always find the lowest cost between two nodes in the current grid? What if it returns smaller cost that in reality?

Comment: @Greyshack you have to write a heuristics that always underestimates the real distance. The easiest way is to do this by removing constraints (in your case obstacles). So yes, it will be enough for heuristics.

Comment: And it will always find the shortest path?

Comment: @Greyshack if your heuristics will be admissible and consistent then yes. Please read wiki page about A*

Comment: But in such case couldn't I just always return 1 or even zero? Or the simplest one is just return max of the dx and dy values. I tried that and it doesn't produce the shortest path always. The latter is consistent according to the wikipedia definition I think.

Comment: @Greyshack yes, you can always return 0. This will be consistent and admissible and ... useless (because this way you would just have dijkstra). The max(dx, dy) is inadmissible. One more time read the wiki page. Based on your questions I can say that you have not read it at all and just went and implemented the algorithm.

Comment: How and when does max(dx,dy) overestimate the cost ? There's no way I can think of that you can reach your target in fewer moves than that. Both horizontal and orthogonal moves reduce the max by one or by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the wikipedia article [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Example). Your heuristic is not "monotonic", because the cost of a given path depends on past choices. Here's my attempt.

Any path can be split into a series of orthagonal movements and a series of diagonal movements. In the heuristic, let's move diagonal until we are orthagonal to the target. That ensures the maximum number of extra costs. NE-NE-E-E.

On the other hand, the best case occurs when we mix orthagonal and diagonal movement evenly: E-NE-E-NE. So for each orthagonal movement, we can treat one diagonal movement as orthagonal.

```
private double heuresticDistance(Node p1, Node p2, bool lastWasDiagonal) {
    int dx = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
    int dy = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
    int diagonals = Math.min(dx, dy);
    int orthagonals = Math.max(dx, dy) - diagonals;
    // example: dx=3, dy=5. Move diagonally 3 times and orthagonally 2 times.

    int temp = diagonals + orthagonals;
    diagonals = Math.max(diagonals - orthagonals, 0);
    orthagonals = temp - diagonals;

    int lastDiagonalBonus = 0;
    if( lastWasDiagonal && orthagonals < 1 )
        lastDiagonalBonus = 1;  // the special case that last move was diagonal and we have no orthagonal moves available to compensate

    if( diagonals % 2 == 1 ) {
        diagonals--; orthagonals++;
    }
    return diagonals * 3 / 2 + orthagonals * 1 + lastDiagonalBonus;
}
```

Comment: Are you taking into account that the first diagonal might cost 2 because we came to the node by a diagonal move? And also that by going firstly orthogonal in order to reduce the cost of the first diagonal might be optimal?

Comment: Even though I included the boolean to take care of that case, I totally forgot. Question updated. You might want to check if my algorithm logic is sound, using pen and paper for a few test cases.

Comment: If last diagonal and it cost 2 then this one will cost 1. I dont think you can do it without this information

Comment: Yeah any heuristic you write needs to know both if the previous move was diagonal and if it was penalized. Maybe you can modify your program to use fractional movement? I.e. 1.5 for every diagonal movement.

Comment: I cant modify it because its based on a game with such rules and im writing a digital version of it :D it has to be exactly the same. I will figure it out eventually